# join where row is distinct

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table where user_id is related to the role a user has, so not necessarily 1:1 user to role, because he can have multiple roles.

I am looking to only select the users which have role_id = 2 and not any other role. Can you assist?

```
select user_id, role_id 
from users u
join roles r on u.user_id=r.user_id
```

(simply adding `where role_id=2` is incorrect).

Current output:

```
user_id  role_id
1        2
1        other
1        3
2        2
3        0
```

Expected output:

```
user_id  role_id
2        2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method using aggregation:

```
select user_id, 2
from roles r
group by user_id
having min(role_id) = 2 and min(role_id) = max(role_id);
```

If `role_id` might be `NULL`, you can adjust this to:

```
having min(role_id) = 2 and min(role_id) = max(role_id) and count(role_id) = count(*)
```

Comment: You can also substitute the second `min(role_id)` with `2`, it will give the same output while being more efficient.

Comment: @Daniele It doesnt account for role_id is null unfortunately (which I didnt include in the example so my bad) so I am getting overstated results.

Comment: This is what I came up with, please let me know if this can be written more efficiently: `select user_id, 2
from 
(select user_id, role_id, count(*) over(partition by user_id) as rn
from roles) a
where rn=1 
group by user_id
having min(role_id) =2 and max(role_id)=2`

Comment: @user8834780 try this one  `Select userid, roleid from user_role
group by userid  having count(roleid) =1 and roleid=2`     Here is link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73df8a/4

Comment: @monikapatel doesnt work as is, it asks for `group by role_id`, which if I add gives incorrect result. MySQL works abit differently

Comment: @user8834780 please check link with demo data in it  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/73df8a/4

Comment: @monikapatel in the language dropdown choose postgresql 9.3 (which is somewhat similar to Redshift, what I am using) and you will see it doesnt run.

Comment: @user8834780: Simply add `AND COUNT(*) = 1`to Gordon's `having`. Your other solution can be simplified to `select user_id, role_id from (select user_id, role_id, count(*) over(partition by user_id) as rn from roles) a where rn=1 and role_id =2`

Comment: @dnoeth By the way if the table contains two identical rows (which shouldn't, but it can) using `AND COUNT(*) = 1` wouldn't work anymore.

Comment: @DanieleMurer: Yep, when a role mapping table contains NULLs it might also contain duplicate rows :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works well with `NULL`s also:

```
SELECT user_id, 2 FROM (
    SELECT user_id, COUNT(role_id)
    FROM roles
    GROUP BY user_id
    HAVING MIN(role_id) = 2 AND MAX(role_id) = 2 AND COUNT(*) = COUNT(role_id)
) AS t;
```

It is huge, but it is the simplest way to do this in PostgreSQL I think.

Comment: Doesnt work as is, it asks for `group by role_id`, which if I add gives incorrect result

Comment: Have you tried executing it? It is ok for me, see [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d5be1/7/0)

Comment: Oh, I got your problem. And I hate SQL dialects. What SQL implementation are you working with?

Comment: I use Redshift which is similar to Postgresql

Comment: @DanieleMurer: I hate dialects which don't follow Standard SQL, too. And MySQL is on top of that list :-)

Comment: Check out my edited answer and let me know if it works now please.

Comment: It will run in PostgreSQL, but fail in most other DBMSes, because the `COUNT(role_id)` has no alias assigned to it. But you don't need the Derived Table, you can simply remove it. And when users with a duplicate role 2 should be returned this will work, too: `having max(case when role_id = 2 then 0 else 1 end) = 0`, it catches both, different values and NULLs.